# Password correct but password is incorrect at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

So whenever I log in and the password is correct it says that the
password is incorrect. How would I fix this

```
<?php
session_start();
require "php/dbc.php";

$username     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$enc_password = md5($password);

if ($username && $password) {
    $query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username'");
    $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrow != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $db_username  = $row['username'];
            $enc_password = $row['password'];
        }
        if ($username == $db_username && $enc_password == $db_password) {
            //echo "Logged in <a href='members.php'>Click here to enter the members area</a>";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
            header("location: members.php");
        } else {
            header("location: top_nav.html?error=Incorrect Password");
        }
    } else {
        header("location: top_nav.html?error=That user doesn't exist");
    }
} else {
    header("location: top_nav.html?error=All fields are required");
}
?>
```

Comment: Start by making your code readable.

Comment: Agree with relentless, if the code looks like that on your screen, then you need to clean it up a lot. If it got mangled in your effort to post it here, perhaps you can edit the post.

Comment: it appears to just be a mangled paste. I tried to format it best I could.

Comment: Read this first: http://php.net/faq.passwords

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in how you get and test the database stored password:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $db_username = $row['username'];
    $enc_password = $row['password']; // this should probably be $db_password
}
if ($username == $db_username && $enc_password == $db_password){ 
// this condition will be false as $db_password is null, 
// and so not equal to $enc_password which is currently set to the database value
```

Your approach is a bit roundabout - typically, I'd query on the username and the encrypted incoming password, rather than load the password from the database for testing later.

Also - you really should pay attention to the big red box on the PHP manual pages for the mysql library:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_connect()
>
> PDO::__construct()

As mentioned in the comments below - you should be making use of PDO and prepared queries

Comment: although I agree with the problem, I don't agree with querying for both username and password. This is just my opinion, but querying for username and checking the password in php is more secure if there is a sql injection. If you query for both the username and password, you are most likely assuming the resultset to be valid which might not be true if sql injection forces the query to pull back other rows. By checking the password in php, sql injection will pull back multiple rows, but php would check the password and none would match. This is just my opinion and probably moot with pdo/mysqli.

Comment: if mysql injection is a concern, then your strategy really won't mitigate it all that much... you're much better off using PDO and prepared statements.